# Is there a satellite tracking software with S-band downlink

Tags: uhf, software

we are trying to track "DTUsat-2" which transmit at 2.402 GHz using automatic frequency adjustment to compensate for Doppler shift. Our receiver ( a professional one) have the ability to set frequency using PC interface. Is there a software that can write the Doppler shift or frequency into a file that can be read and send to receiver for correction. Or should we write our own software?
Help is appreciated

Comment: If you are asking for software recommendations, you *really* need to specify which platform you are on. Software that runs on Windows likely won't be of any use to you if you are running OS X or Linux, for example.

Comment: The platform; 
Model: HPZ820 workstation
Processor:  Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-2620 v2 @2.1GHz 2.1GHz
Installed memory (RAM): 16 GB
System type: 64-bit Operating system
Using Windows 7 Professional 
At the moment we are using HRD sat tracking software

Comment: Look at Gpredict [link](http://gpredict.oz9aec.net/).  It runs on Windows (and linux and Mac) and will compute Doppler corrections.  More interestingly perhaps it interfaces with radios using Hamlib which is open, so if your radio isn't supported out of the box you can roll your own Hamlib module to support it.

Answer (score 1):

An old question but for the sake of a viable answer, the PyEphem library contains all the needed functionality to perform this calculation on a realtime basis.

See my description [here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/7763/9493) on StackExchange.